# getting bch out of my paper wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

Hi anybody who can honestly and simply tell me how to get my bch out of my paper wallet. I went to blockchain.info and transferred my bitcoin which I had on my paper wallet before Aug 1rst--into their wallet, then safely exported it to an exchange I use--all went well. But I haven't the foggiest how to retrieve my bcc from the same paper wallet now, which I've been told still has the bcc on it. blockchains website is not for a newby like me. I sent their support requesting step by step directions and haven't heard back from them--can anybody give me simple directions on how to get my bcc out of my paper wallet and into my exchange? Please don't assume I know anything and I especially only want to deal with my pc to accomplish this---I have no clue what an app is and don't want to know----Is there someone who's right for this question please?

Comment: when you pose your question like this, you might fall victim to scammers. There are already people here in the forum, that told their story of being scammed. So be very careful once you get contacted, and never (ever!) give out your private key or seed(s) to anyone via Internet - you will be robbed!

Answer (score 1):

You could download a full client of bitcoin cash like Bitcoin ABC (https://www.bitcoinabc.org/).
After that you can import your private keys from the paper wallet with the console (help > debug window > console) and enter

```
importprivkey <yourprivatekey> "label of address"
```

The optional "label of address" is just a description for you and not visible for anyone else.

After entering the `importprivkey` command, the wallet has to rescan the wallet for transactions, which may take a few hours depending on your system. After that, your address is fully spendable from within your wallet.

If you want to import multiple private keys, you can disable the rescan option until you entered all private keys with an additional argument. For example, to import 3 private keys you can use 2 times "false" to skip rescan and on the last import "true":

```
importprivkey <yourprivatekey-1> "label of address 1" false
importprivkey <yourprivatekey-2> "label of address 2" false
importprivkey <yourprivatekey-3> "label of address 3" true
```

**Beware**: Ensure that you claim your Bitcoin (BTC) first, and only after successfully sent them to another address use key for claiming your Bitcoin Cash (BCH), because BTC is way more valuable than BCH and I don't know how safe Bitcoin ABC actually is.

This procedure is a bit cumbersome, because you need to download the whole blockchain. But you are not dependent of any third-party applications or websites and don't reveal your private keys to anyone online.

This method can also be applied to any other Bitcoin Fork, assuming that there is a QtWallet for that Fork available.

After claiming your coins I would suggest to never use the address again. Get a new Paper wallet address if you want to use one again.